# Help with an exercise in analysis and measure theory.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

Let $(f_ {n})$ be a sequence of functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that

$\displaystyle\{x\in X:(f_{n}(x))\text{ converges in}\ \mathbb{R}\}=\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{p=1}^{\infty} \{x\in X:|f_{n}(x)-f_{n+p}(x)|<\frac{1}{k}\}$

My attempt was

$(f_{n}(x))\text{ converges}$

iff $\forall \epsilon>0:\exists n\in \mathbb{N}:\forall m\in \mathbb{N}: m>n\rightarrow |f_n(x)-f_m(x)|<\epsilon$

iff $\forall k\in \mathbb{N}:\exists n\in \mathbb{N}:\forall p\in \mathbb{N}:|f_n(x)-f_{n+p}(x)|<\frac{1}{k}$

iff $\displaystyle x\in\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{p=1}^{\infty} \{x\in X:|f_{n}(x)-f_{n+p}(x)|<\frac{1}{k}\}$

I did this, but my teacher told me that I was not demonstrating anything with this. It's wrong? I only used the Cauchy criteria and the archimedean property.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your argument.

Comment: Looks good to me too.

Comment: This looks fine